# How to install program shodan

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux

I have Kali Linux and I want to install `shodan`, but it gives me an error message:

```
$ easy_install shodan
-bash: easy_install: command not found
```

Can you tell me what can I do ?

Comment: As far as I know, Shodan is a search engine, not a program you install. https://www.shodan.io/

Comment: Please note that [Kali is a tool designed for experts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399626/22222). It is not a normal operating system and should not be used as one. The error you are getting is quite clear: you don't have `easy_install`. But if you don't know how to correct that, I would strongly urge you to use a different operating system.

Comment: Does `pip install shodan` work?

Comment: `easy_install` is not installed. Put Kali down and step away. Chose a different distro for you first Gnu/Linux. Debian is good.

Answer (score 4):

As @ctl-alt-delor points out, you do not have `easy_install` installed.

You have to do:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

And then you can already run:

```
easy_install shodan
```

An alternative I pointed out earlier in comments is also doing:

```
sudo apt-get install pip
pip install shodan
```

Answer (score 1):

Shodan is already installed in most penetration and security Linux distros, such as Kali Linux, Parrot Os and BlackArch.

To check If you got Shodan, just enter `Shodan` on terminal.

and you should see the result like this

```
Usage: shodan [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  -h, --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  alert       Manage the network alerts for your account
  convert     Convert the given input data file into a different format.
  count       Returns the number of results for a search
  data        Bulk data access to Shodan
  domain      View all available information for a domain
  download    Download search results and save them in a compressed JSON...
  honeyscore  Check whether the IP is a honeypot or not.
  host        View all available information for an IP address
  info        Shows general information about your account
  init        Initialize the Shodan command-line
  myip        Print your external IP address
  org         Manage your organization's access to Shodan
  parse       Extract information out of compressed JSON files.
  radar       Real-Time Map of some results as Shodan finds them.
  scan        Scan an IP/ netblock using Shodan.
  search      Search the Shodan database
  stats       Provide summary information about a search query
  stream      Stream data in real-time.
  version     Print version of this tool.
```